# Value(s) of X Mean Standard deviation need to find Probability or area under the curve

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statistics, data-science, usage-statistics

An average light bulb manufactured by Acme corporations lasts 300 days with a standard deviation of 50 days . Assuming that bulb life is normally distributed, what is the probability that an Acme light bulb will last at most 365 days?

How can the same be replicated in code in python?

Comment: Is this even a coding related question? Seems like you could do this with pure calculus...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mu = 10*30
std_d = 50
import math
def norm_pdf(x, mean, std):
    variance = float(std)**2
    denom = (2*math.pi*variance)**.5
    num = math.exp(-(float(x)-float(mean))**2/(2*variance))
    return num/denom
norm_pdf(12*30, mu, std_d)
```

[Formula Refrence: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Probability_density_function)